# Set alpha of background of UIButton but not the title

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton

When I set the alpha of the button it also affects the opacity of the title. Is there a way to target only the background and leave the title alpha at 1.0?

Answer (score 25):

This works for me:

```
self.myButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

or if you don't want to have it completely clear, but still with transparency you can use:

```
self.myButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:200.0/255.0 green:200.0/255.0 blue:200.0/255.0 alpha:0.5];
```

The second example would give you gray color with alpha 0.5.

**SWIFT 4 Update**

```
myButton.backgroundColor = .clear
```

OR

```
myButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 200.0/255.0, green: 200.0/255.0, blue: 200.0/255.0, alpha:0.5)
```

Comment: Why couldn't I think of this? Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

You can also change the alpha of the color in the storyboard,

see attached image:

[image: change alpha of color in storyboard/interface builder]

Answer (score 8):

In **Swift**:

```
import UIKit

class SignInUpMenuTableViewControllerBigButton: UIButton {

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.applyCustomDesign()
    }

    func applyCustomDesign() {
        // We set the background color of the UIButton.
        self.clearHighlighted()
    }

    override var highlighted: Bool {
        didSet {
            if highlighted {
                self.highlightBtn()
            } else {
                self.clearHighlighted()
            }
        }
    }

    func highlightBtn() {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.0)
    }

    func clearHighlighted() {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.05)
    }

}
```

**Swift 4.2**

```
import UIKit

class SignInUpMenuTableViewControllerBigButton: UIButton {

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.applyCustomDesign()
    }

    func applyCustomDesign() {
        // We set the background color of the UIButton.
        self.clearHighlighted()
    }

    override var highlighted: Bool {
        didSet {
            if highlighted {
                self.highlightBtn()
            } else {
                self.clearHighlighted()
            }
        }
    }

    func highlightBtn() {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().withAlphaComponent(0.0)
    }

    func clearHighlighted() {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().withAlphaComponent(0.05)
    }

}
```

Comment: Plus one for the `colorWithAlphaCompnent`! For Swift 3: `UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.8)`

Answer (score 1):

Subclassing UIButton and extending the setEnabled: method seems to work:

```
- (void) setEnabled:(BOOL)enabled {    
    [super setEnabled:enabled];
    if (enabled) {
        self.imageView.alpha = 1;
    } else {
        self.imageView.alpha = .25;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this actually work for you?  In iOS 7 I can't seem to change the Alpha settings for the Button's image at all.

Answer (score 0):

With a UIButton, you can remove the background by setting the button style to Custom rather than Round Rect. That keeps the title intact, but the button background removed. If you're doing this in Storyboards, you can change the button style in the element properties. For code, the format is:

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
// Setup frame and add to view
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift  `button.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.7)`

Answer (score -2):

Are you just using a plain colour for the background? Or are you using an image?

If you're using an image then you could use an image with the alpha built in.

If you're using a colour then you could set the alpha on the colour.

However, changing the alpha of any view affects all sub views.